# ajaxcontroltoolkit - asyncfileupload not working with mobile camera

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using asyncfileupload control from ajaxcontroltoolkit and it is working in the mobile (from an asp .net app in the server) , it works if I choose an image from the gallery but if I try to upload a photo from the camera directly it doesn't works, any clue?